# Query performance debuging

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I have recently installed a new module(paypal express) in Oxid 6.0.x backend.
After installation, the backend menu point "orders", in my backend, is timing out. Cause the query needs too long. I am not able to view orders (which is a CMS vendor resource).

I already tried to debug it with our managed hoster support who doubled our ram to increased mysql buffer size as well as php timouts etc. within the php.ini.

After the hoster php.ini change I still see the query with status "Copying to tmp table" even so the hoster has increased the query buffers etc.

**Question:**
I am really not sure what the problem is. Does someone have an Idea what else I might try?
I cannot imagine that this one small join needs so much buffer space and time to excecute. Especially since the join to payppaypalpluspayment is the same as to oxv_oxpayments_de which is instant and on the same primary key.

This is the query I see running in processlist 
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 200.9683 seconds.) Has already decreased from about 10 min after the php.ini change

```
select count(*) from  `oxorder`
       LEFT JOIN `oxv_oxpayments_de` AS `payments` on `payments`.oxid=oxorder.oxpaymenttype
           LEFT JOIN `oxv_oxpayments_de` AS pluspayments ON pluspayments.oxid = oxorder.oxpaymenttype
           LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspayment ON payppaypalpluspayment.OXORDERID = oxorder.OXID
           LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspui ON payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID = payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID
        where 1  and ( oxorder.oxfolder = 'ORDERFOLDER_NEW' )
```

count(*) Result 150000
The problem may be this join, the others are instant results
rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 153.2391 seconds.)

```
Select count(*) from  `oxorder`

           LEFT JOIN payppaypalpluspayment ON payppaypalpluspayment.OXORDERID = oxorder.OXID
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
id select_type  table                   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows        Extra   
1   SIMPLE      oxorder                 index       NULL        MAINIDX     10          NULL    146861      Using index
1   SIMPLE      payppaypalpluspayment   index       NULL        OXORDERID   32          NULL    2630        Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE      payppaypalpluspui       ALL         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    519         Using where
```

Changed after adding suggested indexes in

> oxorder.OXPAYMENTTYPE;
>   oxorder.oxfolder;
>   payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID;
>   payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID;

```
id  select_type     table                   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref                                 rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          oxorder                 ref     OXFOLDER        OXFOLDER    98      const                               73450   Using index condition
1   SIMPLE          payppaypalpluspayment   ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL                                2634    Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE          payppaypalpluspui       ref     OXPAYMENTID     OXPAYMENTID 34      payppaypalpluspayment.OXPAYMENTID   1       Using where; Using index
```

After this count selects the backend is doing the same query with select oxorder.* and one column from payppaypalpluspui  (takes about 600 seconds)
The UI has then already timed out. When I delete the last two joins and try it manually on the server the query takes < 1sec

**dbs**

```
CREATE TABLE `payppaypalpluspayment` (
 `OXID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Payment oxid id',
 `OXORDERID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order id',
 `OXSALEID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment sale id',
 `OXPAYMENTID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment id',
 `OXSTATUS` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment status',
 `OXDATECREATED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Payment creation date',
 `OXTOTAL` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Total payment amount',
 `OXCURRENCY` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Payment currency',
 `OXPAYMENTOBJECT` blob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Serialized payment object',
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `OXORDERID` (`OXORDERID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `OXSALEID` (`OXSALEID`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTID` (`OXPAYMENTID`)    <<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='PayPal Plus payment data model'
```

Rows 3,228  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     11.4 MiB

```
CREATE TABLE `oxorder` (
 `OXID` char(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order id',
 `OXSHOPID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Shop id (oxshops)',
 `OXUSERID` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User id (oxuser)',
 `OXORDERDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Order date',
 `OXORDERNR` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order number',
 .....
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`),
 KEY `MAINIDX` (`OXSHOPID`,`OXSTORNO`,`OXORDERDATE`),
 KEY `OXORDERNR` (`OXORDERNR`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTTYPE` (`OXPAYMENTTYPE`),  <<<< added this index
 KEY `OXFOLDER` (`OXFOLDER`)             <<<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Shop orders information'
```

149,068     InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     258.1 MiB

```
CREATE TABLE `payppaypalpluspui` (
 `OXID` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Payment oxid id',
 `OXPAYMENTID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus payment id',
 `OXREFERENCENUMBER` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI reference_number',
 `OXBANKNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction bank name',
 `OXACCOUNTHOLDER` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction account holder',
 `OXIBAN` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction IBAN',
 `OXBIC` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI banking instruction BIC',
 `OXDUEDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI due date',
 `OXTOTAL` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI Total invoice amount',
 `OXCURRENCY` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PayPal Plus PuI invoice currency',
 `OXPUIOBJECT` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON representation of the payment instructions',
 PRIMARY KEY (`OXID`)
 KEY `OXPAYMENTID` (`OXPAYMENTID`)   <<<< added this index
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='PayPal Plus Pay upon Invoice data model'
```

Rows 655    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     1.5 MiB

innodb buffer pool = 8 GiB 
RAM 10 GiB

Comment: Adding an index on `oxorder.oxpaymenttype` wouldn't hurt. On any of the fields you use to join (or sort...) on.

Comment: I added the index, which did not change the request time

Comment: `payppaypalpluspui      type: ALL`, so no index is used, meaning it does a full table scan. So you need an index on `payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID`.

Comment: yes, currently adding payppaypalpluspui.OXPAYMENTID index... this seems to be taking some time

Comment: That's expected seeing that a full scan took 600 seconds :)

Comment: I have now added 4 indexes, which changes the time of the count select to 170 sec. If you see the EXPLAIN I added, it seems strange that the types changed to ref and all. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid this is where my knowledge fails. I'm not entirely sure why the index on `payppaypalpluspayment.OXORDERID` is not used anymore even though there's a UNIQUE KEY constraint (and thus index) on it. And what's more confusing to me is that the index was used before... There's no index on `oxorder.oxfolder` either, right? So then because it already does a full scan for that maybe it chooses to use the same full scan for the join too.

Comment: I added the oxorder.oxfolder index. After that it went from Using index to Using index condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing columns encoded in different character sets, latin1 and utf8.  In such cases, index may not be used for key look-ups.  You should make sure to use the same character set for all your key columns.

Comment: This was correct, I changed all columns mentioned in the joins to utf8_general_ci and the excecution time went donw from ~25sec to 0.1208. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: originally I thought that the LEFT Join's were not relevant, but in theory they  can inflate the count as pointed out by the comments.

For this count query. All of the LEFT JOIN's seem irrelevant, since the joined do not seem to contain more rows than the left table, and you retrieve only the count, not the data from those. I would remove all of them (if that would be possible, but I now understand that is not the case)

For the oxorder.* query. Do not include joins that you don't use. Also you think of changing the primary key if you always access the joined table in a one on one situation

Comment: these are not my querys, but they are vendor given (from the CMS and the isntalled modules). I could change them, but only with big effort in that I write a new module which overwrites these queries, which might get into problems later when installing other modules which would add to this. So I am trying to solve this beforehand by checking why this would take so long anyways.

Comment: Understood. So what about changing the primary for table payppaypalpluspayment to column oxorderid?

Comment: has no effect at all

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` can inflate the count if multiple rows occur on the 'right'.